# backup and migrate Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: backups

I have tried to use backup and migrate from an existing system into a fresh Bitnami Drupal 7.4.1 Civicrm 4.6.9 install on another machine. Win10
BandM 7.x-3.1
I received the following error:
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1217 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails in backup_migrate_source_db_mysql->_restore_db_from_file() (line 199 of C:\Bitnami\civicrm-4.6.9-1\apps\civicrm\htdocs\sites\all\modules\backup_migrate\includes\sources.db.mysql.inc)
I looked at the existing answers and am unable to get it to work.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Backup and Migrate module may not be compatible with CiviCRM, and may not understand how to handle the many foreign key constraints within CiviCRM.

Here is the easy way:

1. Drop the database entirely (back it up first please)
2. recreate that database with the same name
3. then restore from your backup.

Here is the hard way:
Particularly, if a failed update has altered the table structure of your database, simply restoring may not work with any tool, because the schema has changed. More information:
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Ensuring+Schema+Integrity+on+Upgrades

Comment: Thank you. That was easy, the BAM module had me consumed for hours. This was a few minutes. Thanks so much. My version of PHPMyadmin had an import feature which made it very easy.